# Canonical way for C library layout for distinction of private and public headers

Tags: c, scons

I am trying to write a C library. Having learned in other programming languages that the distinction between private and public API is important when writing a library, so I would like to distinguish private and public API in this library. Now I am looking for a good (and/or canonical) layout for the project directory.

I'd assume, that this kind of would look like this:

```
./include/mylib/testing.h
./SConstruct
./src/SConscript
./src/testing.c
./test/SConscript
./test/test_testing.c
```

and `include/...`  could then be packaged as a `mylib-dev` package for applications to link to (i.e instealled in `/usr/local/include`). Does this sound reasonable?

For reference, I use the following scons configuration:

```
from os.path import join

include = Dir('include')
cflags = ['-Wall', '-std=c11']

common_env = Environment(CPPPATH=include, CFLAGS=cflags)

release_env = common_env.Clone(CPPDEFINES=['RELEASE'])

release_env.VariantDir('build/release/src', 'src', duplicate=0)
release_env.VariantDir('build/release/test', 'test', duplicate=0)

debug_env = common_env.Clone(CPPDEFINES=['DEBUG'], CFLAGS=['-g'])

debug_env.VariantDir('build/debug/src', 'src', duplicate=0)
debug_env.VariantDir('build/debug/test', 'test', duplicate=0)

for mode, env in dict(release=release_env, debug=debug_env).iteritems():
    modeDir = join('build', mode)
    library = env.SConscript(join(modeDir, 'src/SConscript'), {'env': env})
    env.SConscript(join(modeDir, 'test/SConscript'), {'env': env})
```

and `src/SConscript`:

```
Import('env')

env = env.Clone()
lib = env.SharedLibrary('yocto', source=['testing.c'])
```

Comment: I'd expect headers in 2 directories, those for the public in one directory and  private ones in another, possible mixed with the source *.c files

Comment: Please, do not use `VariantDir` directly...instead have a look a the `variant_dir` parameter to the `SConscript` call, as described in the [UserGuide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html), Chapter 15. Separating Source and Build Directories. It will give you less headaches over time. ;)

Comment: I do as @chux describes, and place public headers in the include folder, and private headers in the src folder.  This works well for us.